# JavaFX Spinner works incorrectly. Spinner.valueProperty().addListener changed twice

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, spinner

I do not understand why,if **Spinner call ChangeListener twice**. How can I make it so that call only one time ?

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller {
@FXML
Spinner<Double> spinner;
@FXML
public void initialize(){
    spinner.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(0,350,60,1));

    spinner.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Double>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Double> observable, Double oldValue, Double newValue) {
            System.out.println("Old Value" + oldValue + "New Value" + newValue);
        }
    });
}}
```

**Main.java**

```
 public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root =     FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }}
```

**Out:**

```
Old Value 60.0 New Value 780.0
Old Value 780.0 New Value 350.0
```

Comment: What value do you enter when it is called twice? bigger than 350?

Comment: yes, i input 780 for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `SpinnerValueFactory`:

```
spinner.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(0,350,60,1));
```

The maximum value of the `Spinner` is 350. You enter 780: the value is changing to this value then because of the maximal value it is changing back to 350.

---

**Update:**

By default, the value inside the editor of the `Spinner` is commited, when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.

To avoid auto-bounding you can for example to try to overwrite the default commit logic:

```
spinner.getEditor().setOnAction(e -> {

    String text = spinner.getEditor().getText();
    SpinnerValueFactory<Double> valueFactory = spinner.getValueFactory();
    if (valueFactory != null) {
        StringConverter<Double> converter = valueFactory.getConverter();
        if (converter != null) {
            try{
                Double value = converter.fromString(text);
                if (value >= minValue && value <= maxValue)
                    valueFactory.setValue(value);
                else
                    valueFactory.setValue(Math.max(Math.min(maxValue, value), minValue));

                // This ensures that if the value us e.g. 350, then 450 entered, the text 
                // is updated to 350 again (rather than ramaining 450)
                spinner.getEditor().setText(converter.toString(valueFactory.getValue()));
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                spinner.getEditor().setText(converter.toString(valueFactory.getValue()));
            }
        }
    }

    e.consume();
});
```

and the values are defined as:

```
double maxValue = 350;
double minValue = 0;
spinner.setValueFactory(
    new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(minValue, maxValue, 60, 1));
```

---

**Note:**

The min and max values can be also retrieved from the `SpinnerValueFactory` - unfortunately not in a totally clean way, but with some casting:

```
spinner.getEditor().setOnAction(e -> {
    SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory valueFactory = (SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory) spinner.getValueFactory();

    if (valueFactory != null) {
        StringConverter<Double> converter = valueFactory.getConverter();
        if (converter != null) {
            try {
                valueFactory.setValue(Math.max(Math.min(valueFactory.getMax(), 
                        converter.fromString(spinner.getEditor().getText())), valueFactory.getMin()));

                spinner.getEditor().setText(converter.toString(valueFactory.getValue()));

            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                spinner.getEditor().setText(converter.toString(valueFactory.getValue()));
            }
        }
    }

    e.consume();
});
```

But in this case it is not necessary to store the min and max values, they are got from the factory itself:

```
spinner.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(0, 350, 60, 1));
```

Comment: Yes, but how can i make only ONE call method public void changed() ?

Comment: Another option is to set a `TextFormatter` on the editor, and veto (or modify) changes that would be out of bounds.

Comment: @James_D Yes that's absolutely true. I just did not want to create a tl;dr answer :)